# JSON.parse Unexpected character

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, mongodb

I have a JSON object stored in a mongoDB collection. The object represents the positions of 5 x images, 5 y images, and a tictactoe board image.

On an interval, I send a request to a php file that responds with this object, and then I want to parse that object and move the pieces accordingly.

this is my request:

```
$.getJSON
(
    "e4.php",
    "",
    function(data)
    {
        world = JSON.parse(data);
        moveObjects(world);
    }
);
```

but I get: JSON.parse: unexpected character

When I console.log data firebug gives me the right object so I know it's returning properly.

In e4.php:

```
$criteria = array("name" => "world");

$doc = $collection->findOne($criteria);

$conn->close();

print $doc['world'];
```

where conn is the connection, and collection is the collection I'm working in.

The database is updated in e3.php:

```
$encodedworld = $_REQUEST['data'];

$criteria = array("name" => "world");

$doc = $collection->findOne($criteria);

$doc['world'] = $encodedworld;

$collection->save($doc);

$conn->close();

print $encodedworld;
```

Any ideas? I'm stumped

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to tell if you don't show the JSON. How are you generating it?

Comment: Edited, although it appears the problem was actually in the original code that I posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery's [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) deserializes the JSON for you, so `data` will be an object graph, not a string. From the documentation:

> The `success` callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed using the `$.parseJSON()` method.

So since `data` has *already* been deserialized, you don't want or need to call `JSON.parse` on it. Doing so will implicitly call `toString` on `data`, which will return either `[object Object]` or `[object Array]`, hence `JSON.parse` not liking it as input. :-) Just use `data` directly:

```
$.getJSON
(
    "e4.php",
    "",
    function(world)         // <=== Changed name of argument
    {
        moveObjects(world); // <=== Used it directly
    }
);
```

---

Separately: Unless you declared `world` somewhere you didn't show, your code was also falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You probably wanted to have `var` in there. But with the change above, you don't need the variable at all, so...

Comment: Thank you so much. Not sure how I missed that

Comment: Also, I have world declared with var as a global. I included the world as an argument to make it more clear that moveObjects knew what world was. It was just for the post.